# mvn exec:exec is causing an error

Tags: java, android, maven

I am working on Mac and keep running into this error after doing `mvn exec:exec`.  I have tried `mvn clean` with the reinstall, but nothing seemed to work.  I'm unsure of what I did wrong.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< com.amazon.alexa.avs:sample-java-client >---------------
[INFO] Building Alexa Voice Service Sample Java Client 20160207.8
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ sample-java-client ---
Exception in thread "main" com.amazon.alexa.avs.config.DeviceConfig$MalformedConfigException: provisioningMethod should be either "companionApp" or "companionService".
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.config.DeviceConfig.<init>(DeviceConfig.java:162)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.config.DeviceConfigUtils.readConfigFile(DeviceConfigUtils.java:118)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.config.DeviceConfigUtils.readConfigFile(DeviceConfigUtils.java:50)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.<init>(App.java:39)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.main(App.java:34)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-31T10:37:43-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project sample-java-client: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```